# Started Getting 500 Internal Server Error when searching for user's videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have just started seeing the following error:

```
(500) Internal Server Error.

WebException Response: {
 "error": {
 "code": 500,
 "message": null
 }
}
```

When running the following request to get a user's videos.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2csnippet&forMine=true&type=video&maxResults=50
```

This was working fine previously, does anybody know if something might have broken? We can also reproduce it using the API explorer, e.g.:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=id%252Csnippet&forMine=true&type=video&_h=5&

Comment: Sounds like Google are having a temporary problem, perhaps try again later

Comment: Indeed - this seems to have resolved itself now.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have resolved itself after about a day, must have been a temporary issue with the API.